# Flutter: How to change the FloatingactionButton icon in the BottomNavBar when pressed?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to change the icon of the FloatingActionButton() in the bottom navigation bar when clicked. It works fine but only when I leave the screen and come back? Does anyone know what's wrong? Setstate in the changeIcon() is called which should force a rerendering, or am I wrong?

I would really appreciate some help :)

Edit:
It doesnt even work if I put in the if `this.pressed` bool statement as child. The state of the `this.pressed` flag is changed from false to true (printed the state) but even this does not lead the button to change its icon.

```
     return FloatingActionButton(
            child: this.pressed ? Icon(Icons.people) : Icon(Icons.close),
            onPressed: () {
              changeIcon();
            });
```

The code is attached here:

```
class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  MapRadials buttonProvider;
  Icon fabIcon = Icon(Icons.perm_media);
  FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _screens = [
    FeedScreen(),
    MapScreen(),
    MapScreen(),
    NotificationScreen(),
    ChatScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    floatingActionButton = FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: fabIcon,
    );
  }

  void changeIcon(Icon icon) {
    setState(() {
      fabIcon = icon;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MapRadials radialProvider = Provider.of<MapRadials>(context);
    this.buttonProvider = radialProvider;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.menu,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.filter_list,
                      size: 30.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      size: 30.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavBar(),
      floatingActionButton: this.floatingActionButton,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      body: _screens[_currentIndex],
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      if (index != 2) {
        _currentIndex = index;
        floatingActionButton = getFloatingActionButton(index);
      }
    });
  }

  Widget getFloatingActionButton(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0: // Home
        return FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {});
      case 1: // Map
        return FloatingActionButton(
            child: fabIcon,
            onPressed: () {
              changeIcon(Icon(Icons.save));
            });
      case 2: // Notification
        return FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.clear_all), onPressed: () {});
      case 3: // Chat
        return FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add_comment), onPressed: () {});
      default:
        return FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {});
    }
  }

  Widget bottomNavBar() {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      onTap: onTabTapped,
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      showSelectedLabels: false,
      showUnselectedLabels: false,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.home,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          title: Text('Feed'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person_pin_circle,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            title: Text('Map')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              null,
            ),
            title: Text('Placeholder')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.notifications,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          title: Text('Noftications'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.chat_bubble,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            title: Text('Chat'))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the icon in the state and using `setState()` for it, and that is fine, but notice that `setState()` is rebuilding your widget tree with a `Scaffold` whose `floatingActionButton` parameter is `floatingActionButton: this.floatingActionButton`, and you are setting your `this.floatingActionButton` in the `initState()` method, that will be called only once (whenever the whole Widget is instantiated). Since that `this.floatingActionButton` is only being instantiated once with the initial icon, the rebuild triggered by `setState()` does not render the FAB with the new icon.

Try setting your `this.floatingActionButton` in `didChangeDependencies()` instead of `initState()`, since, according to the [flutter.dev documentation article on didChangeDependecies](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin/didChangeDependencies.html), it will be

> Called when a dependency of this State object changes.

Comment: Thanks for ur fast help. I removed the initiState() method and set the this.floatingActonButton in the didChangeDependencies(). But still, it changes the icon only changes after I switched screens and come back :(

Comment: did you try creating a new FAB instead of reusing the old one? like floatingActionButton: getFloatingActionButton()

Answer (score 0):

Give it a [Key](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html).

Everytime the build function is called, it compares those Keys. For example, if you use UniqueKey, your FloatingActionButton  always gets rebuild, because it will have a new unique key everytime. But in this case you should take the build of your FloatingActionButton out of initState() and put it inside of your widget tree.